# Why won't jQuery on() work on existing elements?

Tags: jquery

I have div with the id of #editor. Within the div is an image with a class of .float-right. I am also dynamically adding new images with the same class to the #editor div. The jQuery code below works on the newly added images, but not the existing ones. Why? I need it both ways.

HTML

```
<div id="#editor">
    <img src="img.jpg" class="float-right">
    <!--jQuery will select this image only if added after page load -->
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#editor').on('click', '.float-right', function() {
//Do stuff
});
```

The rough code I'm working on http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/9tdDa/ (it's a wysiwyg html5 editor)

Comment: Not related to the issue, but you really shouldn't use duplicate IDs.

Comment: Hmm. Didn't think I was! If you see some, let me know.

Comment: Your selector `.img-wrap-left #btn-done` indicates that you might be.

Comment: Ah, that's more an issue of an unnecessary selector than having multiple IDs. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: I am worried that your buttons (with IDs) might be present twice.

Comment: Those IDs show up once you click the image, and you can only open the 'controls' on one image at a time. Therefore, they exist in only one place at time, but may be used in different locations on the page throughout the editing.

Comment: So, your redundant selectors act as IF conditions?

Comment: No, the selectors were unnecessarily specific. I should've just stated  "#btn-done" rather than ".img-wrap-left #btn-done"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're preventing all click events on existing children of #editor with

```
$("#editor").children().click(function(){
    return false;
});
```

remove it (in 2 places) and it works. It doesn't affect new elements because it only targets existing.

http://jsfiddle.net/9tdDa/5/

Comment: Line 65 of his fiddle is one of them. 79 is the other.

Comment: Then it's an issue in Chrome / fiddle editor. `Ctrl+F` doesn't find the string if it's not near the viewport, and it apparently doesn't exist in the DOM somehow.

Comment: Ahhh that's it. Thank you. I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when stack overflow lets me.